# When to use definite vs indefinite article - ambiguity

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm struggling to understand the different uses of definite and indefinite articles in the below examples. I believe that each example is correct, but don't understand why.

Example 1:

- I injured my shin in **the** game last week.
- I injured my shin in **a** game last week.

Example 2:

- I opened **the** present that my aunt gave me.
- I opened **a** present that my aunt gave me.

Example 3:

- Playing at home, Rachel kicked **a** beach ball and it flew out of **a** window.
- Playing at home, Rachel kicked **the** beach ball and it flew out of **the** window.

Comment: There are a lot of different situations here, with different levels of specificity / required tacit contextualisation. I'll answer (3). (3a) is fine, with no prior mention / envisioning of the ball or the window/s involved. We don't know how many balls were in the house  (probably just the one) or how many windows (probably not just the one) the house had. // (3b) demands that the addressee already knows that Rachel has a (and only one) beach ball. The use of 'the' in 'out of the window' almost certainly is idiomatic (as in "He's at the doctor's"), not specifying (a certain / the only) window.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. See [ell.se]. Good Luck.

Comment: 'A game' = any unspecified game. 'The game' = one that the person being addressed knows about - perhaps a regular weekly football game.